# Nested Fields in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to un-nest some nested fields and do a sub-query in Google BigQuery.

This works fine.

```
SELECT id, 
custom_field_options
FROM `project.database.ticket_fields`
```

'custom_field_options' is a nested field, and that's causing some problems for me.  I have 'custom_field_options.id' and 'custom_field_options.name' and a couple other nested fields.

This also works fine.

```
SELECT ticket_fields.id,
ticket_fields.raw_title,
ticket_custom_fields.name AS ticket_custom_fields_name,
ticket_custom_fields.raw_name AS ticket_custom_fields_raw_name,
ticket_custom_fields.value AS ticket_custom_fields_value,
ticket_fields.created_at
FROM `project.database.ticket_fields` AS ticket_fields
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(custom_field_options) AS ticket_custom_fields
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

When run separately, both those queries run fine.  Now, I'm trying to run the first query as a sub-query of the second, to pull back all ids from that query, and based on that, run the query below.

```
SELECT ticket_fields.id,
ticket_fields.raw_title,
ticket_custom_fields.name AS ticket_custom_fields_name,
ticket_custom_fields.raw_name AS ticket_custom_fields_raw_name,
ticket_custom_fields.value AS ticket_custom_fields_value,
ticket_fields.created_at
FROM `project.database.ticket_fields` AS ticket_fields
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(custom_field_options) AS ticket_custom_fields
  WHERE id IN (SELECT id, 
  custom_field_options
  FROM `project.database.ticket_fields`)
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: What is the error? What is the expected result?

Comment: This is my error:  Column name id is ambiguous at [9:9]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can qualify the `id` column name to make the reference unambiguous:

```
SELECT ticket_fields.id,
ticket_fields.raw_title,
ticket_custom_fields.name AS ticket_custom_fields_name,
ticket_custom_fields.raw_name AS ticket_custom_fields_raw_name,
ticket_custom_fields.value AS ticket_custom_fields_value,
ticket_fields.created_at
FROM `project.database.ticket_fields` AS ticket_fields
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(custom_field_options) AS ticket_custom_fields
  WHERE ticket_fields.id IN (SELECT id, 
  custom_field_options
  FROM `project.database.ticket_fields`)
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

(I'm assuming that `ticket_fields.id` is the `id` that you want to search for)

Comment: Yeap, that was the problem.  I forgot about that ; haven't done this in a while.  One more thing, I just changed the sub-query to this: WHERE ticket_metrics.id IN (SELECT id 
  FROM `project.database.ticket_metrics`).  The error reads 'Unrecognized name: ticket_metrics'.  The sub-query works fine and there is definitely a field named 'in' in the table named 'ticket_metrics'.  It's very weird.

Comment: Hard to tell without more context, sorry. If you could post a separate question with more detail, someone may be able to help.